# PowerShell Compare content of two strings

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-1.0

I am trying to compare the values of two variables but the contents of those two strings are in different orders

Example:

```
$Var1 = "item1"
$Var1 += "item2"
$Var2 = "item2"
$Var2 = "item1"
```

How can I compare those two variables to see if they both are equal?

===== UPDATED WITH  EXAMPLE =====
EXAMPLE: Get objects and sort them.

```
$Computers = (Get-Content "$PWD\Computers.txt").GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object {"$_"}
```

EXAMPLE: Add the results and sort them.

```
$Successful += $Computer
$Successful = $Successful.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object {"$_"}
```

EXAMPLE SCRIPT: Used the examples above to create the following script. The example allowed me to check the results, instead of count, but by content allowing me to get more accurate comparison. Before I was using "Successful.count -eq Computers.count" which wouldn't check if a computer was inputted twice.

```
$Computers = (Get-Content "$PWD\Computers.txt").GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object {"$_"}
$HotFixes = Get-Content "$PWD\HotFixes.csv"
CLS
While (!$Successful -OR $Successful -ne $Computers) {
    foreach  ($Computer in $Computers) {
        $MissingCount = 0
        IF (!$Successful -NotLike "*$Computer*") {
            Write-Host "$Computer`: Connecting"
            If (Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -Count 1 -quiet) {
                Write-Host "$Computer`: Connected"
                [string]$Comparison = get-hotfix -ComputerName $Computer | Select -expand HotFixID
                ForEach ($HotFix in $HotFixes) {
                    IF ($Comparison -NotLike "*$HotFix*") {
                        $Results += "$Computer,$HotFix"
                        $MissingCount++
                    }
                }
                Write-Host "$Computer`: $MissingCount Patches Needed"
                $Successful += $Computer
                $Successful = $Successful.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object {"$_"}
            } ELSE {
                Write-Host "$Computer`: Unable to connect"
            }
        } ELSE {
            Write-Host "$Computer already completed"
        }
    Write-Host "$Computer`: Complete"
    Write-Host
    }

}

$Results
```

Comment: The question is not 100% clear, what do you mean by `contents are in different order`? Is the order of characters reversed? From your example, the words are reversed. Different != reversed, for example, it can also be randomized. Please clarify how different your content is (can be), how you want to compare it, and which results you expect to get for some sample strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to find if the content is equal, regardless of characters position, you could break the string to its characters, sort the result and then use the Compare-Object cmdlet. No result means the variables are equal:

```
$v1 = $Var1.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object {"$_"}
$v2 = $Var2.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object {"$_"}
compare $v1 $v2
```

Comment: Superb! Updated answer with your suggestion. Thank you!